# flattening an array with recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

Recursion has been a difficult subject for me so far. As a task am trying to write a code from scratch using recursion. I wrote this function to flatten arrays.

```js
function foo(item) {
  if (item instanceof Array) {
    for (let ii of item) {
      foo(ii);
    }
  } else {
    let bar = item;
    console.log(bar);
    return bar;
  }
}

function arrFlatten(arr) {
  let result = [];

  for (let i of arr) {
    let temp = foo(i);
    console.log(temp);
    result.push(temp);
  }

  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

let bar = [1, [2], [3, [[4]]]];
arrFlatten(bar);
```

I put 2 `console.log()` one is printing the variable `bar` and the other is printing the variable `temp`.

As you can see by running the code, inside the `else` block, `bar` evaluates correctly, but immediately when i return it, the variable `temp` sometimes evaluates to `undefined`.

I want to understand why is that happening, I think is pretty straight to assume that `temp` will always evaluate equal to `bar`.

Comment: Consider the other branch... If `item` is an `Array`, no value is `return`ed from `foo(i)`...

Comment: @tehhowch thanks for the reply. Am not taking into account that all javascript functions returns `undefined` unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if am allowed to reply to my own questions here, but I found the answer, and I don't want to leave this question unanswered.

> As you can see by running the code, inside the else block, bar evaluates correctly, but immediately when i return it, the variable temp sometimes evaluates to undefined.
>
> I want to understand why is that happening, I think is pretty straight to assume that temp will always evaluate equal to bar.

The reason why `temp` sometimes is returning `undefined` is because am not taking into account that all javascript functions returns `undefined` unless otherwise specified.

Those `undefined` are happening at the end of this

```
function foo(item) {
  if (item instanceof Array) {
    for (let ii of item) {
      foo(ii);
    }
  } else {
    let bar = item;
    console.log(bar);
    return bar;
  }
}
```

every time the `for loop` ends and the end of the function is met, the function returns `undefined`.

Knowing that, I had to rewrite the code like this.

```
function foo(item, arr=[]) {
  let result;
  if (item instanceof Array) {
    for (let ii of item) {
      result = foo(ii, arr);
    }
  } else {
    arr.push(item);
    return arr;
  }
  return result;
}


let bar = [1, [2], [3, [[4, 5], 6], 7], 8];
console.log(foo(bar));
```

Is not the most elegant way, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below code, it's just a modification to your answer.

I think this will be a better way to do it and also you will understand it more clearly.

Refer comments in the code for why I made those changes.

```
// You don't need a 2nd argument, so remove it
function flatten(items){
       let result = [];

       // for loop should be outside the if statement 
       for(let item of items){
             if(item instanceof Array){
                    // flatten recursively, returned array will contain flattened subarray
                    var flattenedItems = flatten(item);
                    for(let flattenedItem of flattenedItems){
                           // Since flattenedItems are returned by 
                        // a recursive call to this function itself,
                          // it is guaranteed that all the elements of 
                          // flattenedItems will already flatted
                        // So, its safe to directly push it to result
                          result.push(flattenedItem);
                   }
             }
             else{
                     result.push(item);
                     // do not return here as I moved for loop out of the if statement
            }
       }
       return result;
}

console.log(flatten([1, [2], [3, [[4, 5], 6], 7], 8]));

// 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, this helps me a lot in my learning.

I can see that the main difference is that your code has to run 2 `for loop` because you are not passing an array as a second argument to.

in my case, because am passing the array as a second argument am saving that second `for loop`.

on the other hand, Your code is easier to understand than mine.

again thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage some of the language constructs or native methods to unnest arrays:

```
const a = [[1,2],[3,4]];
```

**Using the spread operator:**

```
[...a[0], ...a[1]];
//=> [1,2,3,4]
```

**Using `concat`:**

```
[].concat(a[0], a[1]);
//=> [1,2,3,4]
```

**With `flatMap`:**

```
a.flatMap(x => x);
//=> [1,2,3,4]
```

You can apply the same principles in a recursive function to unnest arrays at any depth:

*Notice: `flatMap` isn't supported in IE/Edge*

```js
const flatten = arr =>
  arr.flatMap(x =>
    Array.isArray(x) ? flatten(x) : x);

console.log(flatten([1, [2], [3, [[4]]]]));
console.log(flatten([1, [2], [3, [[4, 5], 6], 7], 8]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason `undefined` is printed out to the console is because not all branches of the `foo` function have a return value. If it hits the *if* statement it will return `undefined` (since there is no return value specified).

You could make use of [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to simplify your function (keep in mind that it has limited support). `flat` doesn't flatten endlessly. However the documentation mentions [alternatives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Alternative), from which one does flatten recursively.

> ```
> //to enable deep level flatten use recursion with reduce and concat
> var arr1 = [1,2,3,[1,2,3,4, [2,3,4]]];
>
> function flattenDeep(arr1) {
>    return arr1.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
> }
> flattenDeep(arr1);// [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]
> ```

```js
function flattenDeep(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(
    (acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), 
    []
  );
}

const bar = [1, [2], [3, [[4]]]];
console.log(flattenDeep(bar));
```

Comment: If you want to make `flattenDeep` IE compatible change the arrow function into a normal function.